# threejs collada model location

Tags: model, three.js, collada

I have been working on THREEJS framework to render *.dae models. There are several dae models. I have a problem with the location of the models. When I render them, each model has a different location. I set their location `dae.position.set(0,0,0);` but unfortunately, it doesn't work perfectly.

For example, for one model I have to set the location as `dae.position.set(-2, -31, 6.5);` and then model is on the location(0,0,0). I check it with AXES `axes.position.set(0,0,0);`.

Do you have any idea, why is the model not on the zero location for x,y,z.

Thank you for helping. I am totally new to three.js. I hope I explained myself clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices of the model are offset from the origin, so you are compensating by setting the `dae.position`.

You can automatically adjust the dae position by recentering the model like so:

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( dae ); // compute the bounding box of the model
box.getCenter( dae.position ); // set dae.position to be the center of the bounding box
dae.position.multiplyScalar( - 1 ); // negate the dae.position coordinates
```

three.js r.87

Comment: Thanks a lot. It totally worked for me. But I have an question, could you explain how it worked. For example I don't add the box to the screen (scene.add(box);) but model is anyway centered.