# How can I fit object position to the centre of the scene threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've tried looking into other examples, but all of them suggested that change the camera settings but this is not want I wanted,I wanted to position(translate) the object to be in the origin point of the scene, as you can see, different object will be loaded in different positions.

[Object 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDszt.png)
[Object 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTNrf.png)

Comment: For one way, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31521622/1461008)

Comment: That totally worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be marked as a duplicate then?